# Success message after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am having a form to get the user details.
Once form is submitted the page gets loaded. I want to display a success message after page loading.

```html
<form name="myForm" class="contactus-template" method="post" onsubmit="return Formvalidation()">
</form>
```

```
function Formvalidation(){
    var validate = validateForm();
    if( validate == true ){
        alert("success");
    }
    else{
        alert("not success");
    }
    return validate;
}
```

This is script I am using now. This gives alert before page reload. I want to do this after that return function.

Comment: Hey did you try onClick method?

Comment: @NitinBisht Yea I tried. It didn't work. I used cookies to show the success message after page load.

Answer (score 0):

I realized you commented on a solution saying you used cookies. You can also use localStorage, and I believe this method is more friendly (and less complicated) for static websites.

On the `Formvalidation` function, you can set a success value to localStorage, then when the new page loads, it checks if that success value is true, shows the success message, then removes the success value from the localStorage.

Here is an example:

```
function Formvalidation(){
var validate = validateForm();
if( validate == true ){
    alert("success");
}
else{
    alert("not success");
}

// Add this, make sure all localStorage values are strings
localStorage.setItem("formSuccess", JSON.stringify(true));

return validate;
}
```

Then, on your new page/reloaded page, use a window load event listener to check if formSuccess is true:

```
window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  const isSuccessful = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formSuccess"));
  
  if (isSuccessful) {
    console.log("submission successful!");
  }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call `Formvalidation()` when the user clicks the submit button, `onsubmit="return Formvalidation()"` should simply be `onsubmit="Formvalidation()"`.

Comment: No I am having few validations in the script which needs to be checked, so I used return.

Comment: @AjayViknesh if you're trying to postpone submission until validations are complete, you should using `preventDefault()` until that's the case...

Answer (score -1):

Use Bootstrap Notify: http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/

And this script:

```
    Alert = {
      show: function(type, title, message, url, delay) {
        $.notify({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            url: url,
            target: "_blank"
        },{
            type: type,
            showProgressbar: false,
            placement: {
                from: "bottom",
                align: "center"
            },
            delay: delay
        });
      },
    }
```

Then you can calling a message with PHP if page is reloaded:

```
echo '<script>Alert.show("success", "", "Form submit success!", "", 3000);</script>';
```

Comment: Thanks, but alert didn't work out for that. I used cookies to show the message.